# One Input type=range with two handlers in HTMl

Tags: html

I want to know is it possible to have one input by type=range with two handlers without any js code?Such as range slider written by jquery.

```
 <input type="range" min="0" max="24" value="0" step="1" id="range"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using just plain HTML, the answer is NO but you can do it using a js library and two `<inputs>`  .

Import `nouislider`:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/nouislider@14/distribute/nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/nouislider@14/distribute/nouislider.min.js"></script>
```

Then add this wherever you need that two-handled slider:

```
<label>
            <input type="hidden" name="range_min" id="range_min">
            <input type="hidden" name="range_max" id="range_max">
            <div id="Range"></div>
            <span id="rangeValue"></span>
            <script>
                var slider = document.getElementById('Range');
                var rangeValue = document.getElementById('rangeValue');
                var min = 0;
                var max = min + 50;
                
                noUiSlider.create(slider, {
                    start: [0, 50],
                    connect: true,
                    step: 10,
                    range: {'min': min, 'max': max},
                });
                
                slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle) {
                    var formattedValues = values.map(val => Number(val).toFixed(0));

                    rangeValue.innerHTML = formattedValues.join(' - ');
                    document.getElementById('range_min').value = formattedValues[0];
                    document.getElementById('range_max').value = formattedValues[1];
                });

            </script>
        </label>
```

**Addition:**

if you are using the snippet in a **Persian (Arabic)** website, use the styling below for the `<label>` to work properly:

```
<label style="direction: ltr;">
```

and also change the `noUiSlider.create` to:

```
                noUiSlider.create(slider, {
                start: [0, 50],
                connect: true,
                step: 10,
                range: {'min': min, 'max': max},
                direction: 'rtl' // this makes different
            });
```

Answer (score -4):

Yea its Possible to do this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
Points: <input type="range" name="points" min="0" max="10">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**For more Details  [Go there](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_range.asp)**